# How to get a MudBlazor table to display on screen

Tags: razor, blazor, blazor-webassembly, mudblazor

I have a `<MudBlazor>` table (mudblazor.com) that has the following layout on the Razor page:

```
<MudTabs>
  <MudTabPanel>
    <ChildContent>
      <MudTable Items="@MyStuff" Hover="true" Striped="true" Virtualize="true" Breakpoint="Breakpoint.Sm" FixedHeader="true">
```

The data is shows is essentially a dictionary<string, string> where the value can contain a lot of data.

To take advantage of virtualisation, I think I have to set the Height property.  I do so (`Height="680px"`) and it fits on my screen great.  Well, until I don't have the screen maximised that is.

What I really want to do is to have it so that the table appears so that it's got a bit of a space around it, but always fits to the page.

I'm using the default layout from Microsoft, so have the navigation meny down the LHS.

I've seen examples of how to do this for an [image](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/mEwRklPfyNXOwSBq), but I can't get it to work for my table.

Comment: Does `100vh` work? That would set it to 100% of the current viewport. You may have to scale that back to a smaller percentage to make it display properly. I'm not sure if `vh` is supported nor whether that will trigger the virtualization for you.

Comment: Hi Lex, I did try `Height: 95vh` but it just disappeared off the bottom of the screen.  However, your comment made me think so tried this again with a much smaller value and boom, worked.  Just need to tinker to get it the right size.  Thanks!

Comment: Not sure how to mark you comment as the answer to give you the credit

Comment: Playing around with this some more, it works to a certain extent, but as the browser height becomes about 75% the screen height, it goes off the bottom of the screen.

Comment: What if you put it inside a `div` with the `vh` setting and then make your table 100%?

Comment: Hi @Lex, tried the div approach.  It seems to break the layout of the LH navigation panel,  and it seemed to have no effect on the height of the table (vertical scoll bar shows this)